# how do you filter a Pandas dataframe by a multi-column set?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to filter a large dataframe by comparing multiple columns against a set of tuples where each element in the tuple corresponds to a different column value?
For example, is there a `.isin()` method that compares multiple columns of the DataFrame against a set of tuples?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 1],
    'b': [2, 2, 0],
    'c': [3, 3, 3],
    'd': ['not', 'relevant', 'column'],
})

# Filter the DataFrame by checking if the values in columns [a, b, c] match any tuple in value_set
value_set = set([(1,2,3), (1, 1, 1)])

new_df = ??  # should contain just the first two rows of df
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), but first is necessary create tuples by first 3 columns:

```
print (df[df[['a','b','c']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(value_set)])
```

Or convert columns to index and use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
print (df[df.set_index(['a','b','c']).index.isin(value_set)])

   a  b  c         d
0  1  2  3       not
1  1  2  3  relevant
```

Another idea is use inner join of [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by helper `DataFrame` by same 3 columns names, then `on` parameter should be omit, because join by intersection of columns names of both df:

```
print (df.merge(pd.DataFrame(value_set, columns=['a','b','c'])))
   a  b  c         d
0  1  2  3       not
1  1  2  3  relevant
```